# Null Pointer Exception while retrieving json object using php?

Tags: php, android, json, nullpointerexception

android code:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Login_Prefs", 0);

            username = prefs.getString("username", "defValue");

            String url = "http://www.iloveexpressions.com/eh/viewFriendList.php";

            nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);

            Log.d("Parameters ", username);

            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username.trim()));

            Log.d("name value pairs", nameValuePairs.toString());

            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "POST",
                    nameValuePairs);

            Log.d("Printing after json", json.toString());

            success = json.getString("success");

            Log.d("Success : ", success);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Error : ", e.toString());
        }
```

php code:

```
  <?php

require 'connection.php';

   $response = array();

if(isset($_POST["username"]))
 {
$username = $_POST["username"];

$response["success"] = 1;

echo json_encode($response);
 }
else
 {
$response["success"] = 0;

echo json_encode($response);
}

?>
```

This is the error i get in log :

```
Parameters(30889): aaa

name value pairs(30889): [username=aaa]

Error :(30889): java.lang.NullPointerException
```

How do I solve this error ? I am using the same method to send and retrieve data using php on android and it works fine ? I am returning success if username is sent to php file correctly

I am using the doInBackground process in a fragment and calling the execute() method in the onCreateView() method is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use google's Volley library. It is fast as compared to this method and work asynchronously.

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
  JsonObjectRequest  jsonObject = new JsonObjectRequest  (Request.Method.POST,"http://www.iloveexpressions.com/eh/viewFriendList.php", new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("usename",username);    
            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            return params;
        }
    };
    queue.add(jsonObject);
```

in `public void onResponse` method you will get your required json response.

Comment: Thank You Faisal I will definitely have a look into that.

Comment: I had not initialized my JSONParser jsonParser; I changed that to JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser(); and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I had not initialized my JSONParser jsonParser;
 I changed that to JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser(); and it worked